# Cant select radio button when one is already checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have object of items whitch i am mapping

```
const paymentMethods = [
    {
        name: 'Blik',
        checked: true
    },
    {
        name: 'Przelewy24',
        checked: false
    }
]



            {paymentMethods.map((el) => (
            <PaymentContainer>
                <Label>{el.name}</Label>
                <RadioButton type="radio" name="payment" value={el.name} onClick={(e) => handleSetPayment(e)} checked={el.checked} />
            </PaymentContainer>
        ))}
```

My problem is when i passing checked property this way

I can't select one where `checked` value is default `false`

Comment: You're setting value={el.name}. Where do you define el?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, already edited

Answer (score 0):

There should be a checked attribute use that.

```
const paymentMethods = [
    {
        name: 'Blik',
        checked: true
    },
    {
        name: 'Przelewy24',
        checked: false
    }
]

         {paymentMethods.map((el,i) => (
            <PaymentContainer key={i}>
                <Label>{el.name}</Label>
                <RadioButton type="radio" name={el.name} value={el.name} onClick={(e) => handleSetPayment(e)}  checked={el.check}/>
            </PaymentContainer>
        ))}
```

Comment: This way i can't select other button

Comment: The name attribute should be unique. lookout the changes. let me know if it fixes the issue and also whenever you use map you should associate the parent wrapper with key.

Comment: Still i cant select other buttons

Comment: can you reference the component used in this . which package you have used?

Comment: What do you mean by, can't select other button?

Comment: When i click on any other select button nothing changes. Always button named "Blik" is checked wherever i click